What does output="0" do and mean?
I use in Visual Studio Code the app Magento 2 Snippets from Jerry Lopez.
If I generate a container,
<container name="" label="" output="0" htmlTag="" htmlId="" htmlClass="" />

I get the option
output="0"

Could you tell me, what does it do and mean?
Thank you very much.

In Magento 2 layout XML files, the output="0" attribute within a  element controls whether the content of that container is rendered (output) on the frontend.

Thanks for the answer.
Is it right, so I can set "1" to show the element and "0" to hide?

output="0": This means the container will not produce any output in the rendered HTML. It effectively disables rendering of the container and any child elements inside it. This can be useful if the container or its content is only needed in specific contexts or for programmatic use.
output="1": When set to 1, the container's content will be rendered as part of the HTML output.

Thank you, you were very helpful.
